# Can rebooting many times cause problems

Tags: bios, reboot, overclocking

I will be overclocking and configuring my rig in about an hour and I decided to try out everything individually. This means I will reboot my computer 30-40 times, maybe even 50 within hours. Can this create issues in my OS 14.10? Don't just say "oohh linux can handle anything" I want an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal experience, rebooting lots of times tends to speed up Ubuntu.  I'm not exactly sure why, but it does.  Overclocking can cause permanent damage and thus permanent slowing.

Comment: Maybe swap gets filled with the "needed@boot" stuff up front... Or maybe you get hypnotized watching & it just seems faster ;-)

Comment: I'm surprised that my answer, however accurate, was chosen as the best answer.

Comment: @Xen2050, no it does not just seem faster.  Bot in terms of booting and the annoying load times for software.  I've timed it, as in, with a timer, not just counting backward from 10 thinking about microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just configuring BIOS-type settings, and running the actual OS doesn't matter except to check stability, you could boot from a live iso (cd/dvd/usb) and not touch your "real" OS. Could even unplug the HD...

I don't know of any problems from rebooting so often, probably write a bunch of log files

Comment: That would only alow everything down, however the log files is somethijg to consider

Comment: You mean slow? Booting from a 20-30MB/sec USB might take a minute or so before it's on the desktop running, only one way to know for sure: Time one & compare to regular boot, see if it's worth it. Could even boot to a different distro, some may be faster than others. Mint doesn't have that "install or try" window, or another? Never searched for distros by fastest boot time...

Comment: I already know, its not worth it . my setup boots in about 7 seconds on ssd rather than a minute as usb, theres a very large difference

Comment: That from a complete cold boot after regular shutdown? Or to resume from suspend or hibernation? My computer barely gets past POST in 7 seconds... If your ssd's that lightning fast you could copy the iso onto it & modify your grub boot menu to read the iso from there too, no usb needed at boot

Comment: Yoyr post is slow because its configured to be slow. My bios is configured to entirely skip anything it does except the motherboard check prior to the beep. And if post is slow, then doesnt that mean the slow usb boot would be even slower?

Comment: I can spare 5 seconds for post :) Maybe you missed the "copy the iso to SSD" part, then boot from there, many multiboot usb's that use GRUB use the technique. Once it's copied you unplug the USB, throw it away, and boot the iso from SSD

Comment: The way you said it sounded like more work "copy the iso modify it..." Thats why i missed it